# Mouseover event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, jquery-events

I have the following `mouseover` function:

```
$('.msg_id').live("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    tid = $(this).attr('id');
    idx = $(this).attr('name');
    resp=""; 
    
    $.ajax({
        async: false, 
        url: "log_msg.asp",
        data: $("#msgForm").serialize() + "&aktion=popup&msg_id="+tid+"&msg_id"+idx,
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+tid).html(data);   
        }
        });

    //$.post("log_msg.asp", $("#msgForm").serialize() + "&aktion=popup&msg_id="+tid+"&msg_id"+idx,
        //function(data) {          
          
        //}).success(function(){
            //$("#"+tid).html(data);     
             //resp=data;
             //$('#bub'+tid).css('display', 'block');   
             //popd.css('display', 'block');    
            //});
    });
```

It puts some html code inside `.msg_id` ( `$("#"+tid).html(data);` ).
The function `mouseover` is called in a loop. The ajax request is sent all the time while mouseovering it, not only once.
How can I fix it?
I have also tried `mouseenter`, but it fires in a loop too.

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you using `mouseover` for this? Why not `click`?

Comment: does it's something happening under the mouse cursor after the putting html content?

Comment: i'm usin mouseover because i want the events fire while mouseovering it , not whiole clicking it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the [mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event instead, as mouseover will fire upon every move inside the element.

```
$('.msg_id').live("mouseenter", function() {
    //Do work here
});
```

or if live isn't required, simply:

```
$('.msg_id').mouseenter(function() {
    //Do work here
});
```

**[MouseOver()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/):**

- Will fire upon entering an element can fire inside of any child elements.

**[MouseEnter():](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)**

- Will fire upon entering an element, and only that element.

Comment: where did you get those descriptions? they validate the confusion around what they actually do...

Comment: It's not necessary, was just mimicking it as OP used a live event in his. I'll include a non-live version as well.

Comment: ahh, didn't notice they used live.

Comment: The descriptions are from the jQuery documentation.

Comment: yeah, they need to have better explanations, it sounds like mouseover should work fine for the OP from that description.

Comment: I removed the quotes as they were a bit difficult to understand, added simpler summaries.

Comment: i need live version, cuse the page is dynamic and objects with class .msg_id are added later by ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)